# Rails 4.1 ActiveRecord - Using Associated Model Properties in Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, model

I'm building a search in my app, and I have three models: Company, Car, and Owner

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :owners
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Each model has a `name` field.

I'm trying to write an ActiveRecord query that returns all owners whose names, car name, or car's company name contains the search query. So if the owner's name doesn't contain the search query but his car's name does, the owner will still be returned.

Here's what I've got going so far:

```
sql_query = "%honda%"

@results = Owner.includes(:car => :company).where("name LIKE ? OR cars.name LIKE ? OR companies.name LIKE ?", sql_query, sql_query, sql_query)
```

However, I'm receiving the following error message when the query is run:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cars"
```

I've looked at the marked answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149340/nested-association-join-in-rails) SO question, but the answer doesn't seem to be working when I apply it to my models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are after a join, not an include. An includes statement will preload the car and company records that are associated with the results of the query. The query is failing because you haven't joined to the `cars` or `companies` table. Try replacing `includes` with `joins` as I don't think includes will be necessary (unless after running the search you will need to know the owner's car and company, in which case preloading will improve performance)

Comment: I tried replacing `includes` with `joins`, and it unfortunately didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `references` method in order for Rails to add the JOIN it needs. [Like so](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references).

Your code would turn into

```
@results = Owner.includes(:car => :company).where("name LIKE ? OR cars.name LIKE ? OR companies.name LIKE ?", sql_query, sql_query, sql_query).references(:cars, :companies)
```

Please notice that `references` uses the actual table name, unlike `includes` which uses association names

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It does the same thing, but I ended up changing the syntax for the `includes` to Rails 3+ like so: `@results = Owner.includes(car: [ :company ]).where("name LIKE ? OR cars.name LIKE ? OR companies.name LIKE ?", sql_query, sql_query, sql_query).references(:cars, :companies)`